# Where Clause on two column sequentially

Tags: sql, select, mariadb

I want to select query where I can fetch records from a table based 2 column where timestamp value match in both column sequentially.

```
SELECT *
FROM commerce_order
WHERE CHANGED BETWEEN 1638342000 AND 1641020400
  AND created BETWEEN 1638342000 AND 1641020400
```

Like column changed update 31st at 10 AM and Column created have value 31 at 11AM both should be shown in the result 1 10 AM then next in 11 PM

```
10 AM
11 AM
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Comment: @Stu I tagged the RDBMS

Comment: You need an `or`. Then something like `group by id having count (*) = 2` and `min(coalesce(change, created))`

Comment: @shawnt00 In case I use column name in place *

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So the "created" timestamp should be 1 minute after the "changed" timestamp?

Then you could truncate them on the minute to compare them.

```
select *
from commerce_order
where changed between unix_timestamp('2021-12-01 07:00') and unix_timestamp('2022-01-01 07:00')
  and cast(date_format(from_unixtime(created), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS datetime) = cast(date_format(from_unixtime(changed), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS datetime) + interval 1 minute
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=79ca14f2c25c9306de3d2a85756a674a)*